# Rotating labels using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I'm writing Python code for ArcGIS using the arcpy library and now I'm experiencing a little problem with labels. In fact I'm not able to rotate them in layout via arcpy (I should rotate all labels of 90 degrees). I found a way to display correct field, round the number, but not to position the label correctly.

Comment: you can fill a field containing the angle of rotation using arcpy, then make a maplex rule to rotate using that field http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000037000000

Comment: Hi @geogeek , thank you for answering. How can I build a maplex rule for my code? I tried to find something about it.. but I couldn't find anything about the syntax to use.. thanks once again!

Comment: Hi @Annalisa Minelli you can only set Maplex rule using maplex toolbar in Arcmap, there's no way so set Maplex rule using arcpy, i think that there's a way to set a rule using Arcobjects. but you can set that rule using ArcMap once time then run the arcpy script to update the field of rotation angle later.

Comment: As a workaround you could try rotating the labels of your layer and save that as a layer file, then when you need rotated labels for that layer use AddLayer to add the layer file.

Comment: I just looked at ArcGIS Ideas to see if anyone had already asked for this but no luck.  You may want to add a new ArcGIS Idea and post a link here so we can add votes to it.

Comment: if you have some experience in arcobjects , you can bring arcobjects functions using Ctypes http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/extend_python.pdf

Comment: thanks @PolyGeo.. do you know if it's possible for example to copy the label style from an external file? because my layer is generated by the script - and if I could only copy the style for the labels (from an external layer - with the same specifics - labels rotated) ..this could be really GREAT :-)

Comment: @geogeek, thanks. I'll have a look at it - I was just wonderin' myself if Arcobject was a solution.. but, from waht I see, it seems I need more time than I have to implement this solution.. (evenif I know a little C, I should study all Arcobject structure..) but, if I cannot do otherwise, for sure I'll do.

Comment: i've just found another relatively simple comtypes use in python, it's pretty simple http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/arcmap_and_python.pdf , http://www.ingeografos.com.pe/2012/04/python-y-arcobjects-2da-parte.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to [your comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/how-to-rotate-labels-using-arcpy?rq=1#comment47842_35321)

> if it's possible for example to copy the label style from an external file?

you should be able to just use Save As Layer File to create your *.lyr with rotated labels.

The *.lyr file can be added into your map using arcpy.mapping.AddLayer and then use arcpy.mapping.replaceDataSource to change that layer's source to the dataset whose labels you want to see rotated.